# flip keys and values from a literal record type

Tags: typescript, type-level-computation

In typescript, given a record literal, how do I switch the keys with the values?

That is:

```
type Foo = { x: "a", y: "b", z: "c" };
```

I wish to be able to write `type Flip<X>` such that:

```
type Bar = Flip<Foo>; // should be { a: "x", b: "y", c: "z" };
```

This is purely a play on types -- not on runtime values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done through the use of [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as).

```
type Flip<T extends Record<any,any>> = {
     [K in keyof T as T[K]]: K 
}
```